# Is Katy Perry's song "The One That Got Away" homage to Titanic?

Tags: reference, titanic, music-video

Katy Perry's song *The One That Got Away* always reminds me of *Titanic*:

Old women remembering her dead love form her young days who is apparently a painter. Which is the exact premise of Titanic, both women married someone else after there love's death but still can't forget their love interest. In the end both go on edge of the boat/hill and remember their love.

So is Katy Perry song homage to Titanic or is it inspired from the film?
Did they ever addressed the similarity?

Comment: I still don´t get it if content of music-videos are on-topic or off-topic. On help-center "music" gives ZERO results. On meta there are quite a few discussions. And this does no state anything clear on the matter: https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289/music-videos-on-topic/1277#1277

Comment: @Paharet that meta is about Music ID, which this question is not, more relevent meta post [Is the Movies and TV Stack Exchange site the best for asking about music videos?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/512/is-the-movies-and-tv-stack-exchange-site-the-best-for-asking-about-music-videos) or [What do you think of this music video question?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/729/what-do-you-think-of-this-music-video-question).

Comment: Even we have a [tag:music-video] tag which say "For questions relating to movie aspects and production of Music Videos. This tag is NOT to be used for Identification of specific music videos, songs or performers IN the music video.".

Comment: Thanks for other two discussions, but if you read closely, you see its not just about Music-ID, but as well analysis of content, production etc. Thus far the statement that Music-ID is off-topic and analysis of content on-topic remains. Just wanted to clarify this over, because previously mentioned many times as "gray area" and take that as future example.

Comment: @Paharet this question is not just about the music video only but about film also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is never stated that the song was paying homage to the Titanic. Katy Perry  stated in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=177&v=7ZCF8s9FkUA) video that the song was about Josh Groban.

You can also read about the music video in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_One_That_Got_Away_(Katy_Perry_song)#Background) wiki article.